# pass a global between two scopes angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am designing a HTML Page:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id='cssmenu'>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li class='has-sub'>
                            <a href='#'><span>Simulink</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#' data-ng-click='bind("Scope")'><span>Scope</span></a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='#' data-ng-click='bind("XY Graph")'><span>XY Graph</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'>
                            <a href='#'><span>Communications</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#' data-ng-click='bind("Constellation diagram")'><span>Constellation diagram</span></a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='#' data-ng-click='bind("Eye diagram")'><span>Eye diagram</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'>
                            <a href='#'><span>DSP</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#' data-ng-click='bind("Matrix viewer")'><span>Matrix viewer</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' data-ng-click='bind("Spectrum Analyser")'><span>Spectrum Analyser</span></a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='#' data-ng-click='bind("Waterfall")'><span>Waterfall</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='last'><a href='#' ng-click="add()"><span>Attach to Model</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Product Type</th>
                            <th>Product ID</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input ng-model="newProduct.productName" class="form-control" /></th>
                            <th><input ng-model="newProduct.productId" class="form-control" /></th>
                            <th><input ng-model="newProduct.productPrice" class="form-control" /></th>
                            <th>
                                <button ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
                            <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.productType}}</td>
                            <td>${{product.productId}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button ng-click="delete(product)" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the Controller Javascript:

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

        });

        app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {

            $scope.bind = function (e) {
                id = e;
                console.log(id);
            };

            $scope.products = [];

            $scope.add = function (id) {
                var newProduct = {
                    productName: id,
                    productType: id,
                    productId: 1
                };
                $scope.products.push(newProduct);
            }

            $scope.delete = function (product) {
                var index = $scope.products.indexOf(product);
                $scope.products.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

My problem is that when I click on any link then the `$scope.bind` function is getting called. Then after selecting the Link i click on the Attach Model link which inturn calls the `$scope.add` function. I have to pass the static data of the link i.e XY Graph to the `add` function so that i can append the data to the Table using ng-repeat.

Can anyone point the issue in my script?

Comment: `$scope.add()` has an argument `id` but in markup you don't have argument

Comment: i am passing the id from the previous function $scope.bind, and this is causing the error !!!! the thing is i have to pass the data from $scope.bind i.e ('id' value to the 'add' function such that a new product is added to the table with the exact selected product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` argument hides the global `id` in the `add()`'s function scope. To access the global `id`, you can just omit the argument.

```
$scope.add = function () {
    var newProduct = {
        productName: id,
        productType: id,
        productId: 1
    };
    $scope.products.push(newProduct);
}
```

However, I don't recommend to use global variables because they can be mutated by other code including 3rd party libraries. You can keep the `id` as a property of the controller scope.

```
$scope.bind = function (e) {
    $scope.id = e;
    console.log($scope.id);
};

$scope.add = function () {
    var newProduct = {
        productName: $scope.id,
        productType: $scope.id,
        productId: 1
    };
    $scope.products.push(newProduct);
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Shuhei Kagawa. I got the id passed to the $scop.add function using the first design i.e directly reference the id. But the second method was not working properly for me !!! But now my functionality works fine. Thanks once again